# Hook isn't printing

Tags: hooks

I've this hook.

```
function modsubmit_webform_submission_insert($node, $submission) {
  $value = array_shift($submission->data);
  $value = array_shift($value['value']);
  print ($value);
  //$value is now the first value entered (in the case of multi-entry fields) or only value entered.
}
```

It does not print the message. Can anyone see what is wrong? Of course, the hook is called when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 1):

**Where are you wanting $value to be printed at?**

Since this function runs in the background when a webform submission is inserted into the webform_submissions table, you need to be explicit about what you want to have happen. Try drupal_set_message() instead, to print a message into the $messages region upon the next successful page callback, which is likely the "submission successful" page:

```
function modsubmit_webform_submission_insert($node, $submission) {
  $value = array_shift($submission->data);
  $value = array_shift($value['value']);
  drupal_set_message("The value inserted was: {$value}");
}
```

Make sure you've installed this module and make sure that you've cleared your cache (admin/config/development/performance) if you've added this function to an existing, already-installed module.